# Rickshaw strange values on the scale

Tags: graph, scale, rickshaw

I use RickShaw to creat some graph, the only problem is the values of the second Y-Axis as you can see on fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/tWXzL/419/

I put a scale between [0,50]

```
var scale2 = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 50]).nice();
```

But the second scale  **axis1** show value between 0 and 1 and not between 0 and 50.

Maybe i don"t understand how it's works, but for the first scale it works perfectly, so why the second scale doesn't work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second y-axis is not of the the ".Scaled" type.
Fixed example: http://jsfiddle.net/tWXzL/477/

```
var y_axis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y.Scaled( { /*Scaled missing*/
    graph: graph,
    orientation: 'right',
    scale: scale2,
    grid: false,
    tickFormat: Rickshaw.Fixtures.Number.formatKMBT,
    element: document.getElementById('axis1'),
} );
```